# How can I load an AutoCompleteTextView from a list of Firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview, firebaseui

If I want to load a list of data into an `AutoCompleteTextView` in android from Firebase, how will  I do that?

**How I'd imagine it:**

I get the data using something similar to a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, and set that adapter to the ACTV. For example, if I have this data:

```
AutoComplete:{
  JKDJKADJKADFJAKD:{
      name:"Hakuna Matata , your orangeness -- I mean your highness, Mr. Trump!"
   }
  JDKIKSLAIJDKDIKA:{
      name:"Hakuna Matata! I ask not to take offense by the previous statement."
   }
}
```

The ACTV should have both statements as suggestions when I type in "Hakuna Matata". Is there any special Firebase adapter for this?

Comment: You'll have to write the code for that yourself. Firebase queries with `startAt` and `endAt` are the likely way to go. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so startAt() gets all the values from the specified key?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you link me to an example?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did it. I'd like to know what you think of my code mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After 6 hours of research, I finally did it thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492827/how-to-get-a-string-list-from-firebase-to-fill-a-spinner).

Here's my database:
[image]
Follow the comments in the following code to achieve what I needed:

```
//Nothing special, create database reference.
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //Create a new ArrayAdapter with your context and the simple layout for the dropdown menu provided by Android
    final ArrayAdapter<String> autoComplete = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    //Child the root before all the push() keys are found and add a ValueEventListener()
    database.child("AutoCompleteOptions").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //Basically, this says "For each DataSnapshot *Data* in dataSnapshot, do what's inside the method.
            for (DataSnapshot suggestionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //Get the suggestion by childing the key of the string you want to get.
                String suggestion = suggestionSnapshot.child("suggestion").getValue(String.class);
                //Add the retrieved string to the list
                autoComplete.add(suggestion);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    AutoCompleteTextView ACTV= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actv);
    ACTV.setAdapter(autoComplete);
```

Comment: Thanks for the efficient solution and your time. You saved me 6 hours!
If you are also updating the `AutoCompleteOptions` in Firebase, you will want to add `autoComplete.clear();` straight after `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {...`. Otherwise when the listener is fired again, the results are simply added to the already populated ArrayAdapter, doubling up on all entries that were previously added to the ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter <String> adp;
uname=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.uname);
adp = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,list);
uname.setThreshold(1);
uname.setAdapter(adp);
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            if(dsp!= null){
                for (DataSnapshot dsp1 : dsp.getChildren()){
                    list.add(String.valueOf(dsp1.getKey()));
                    adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```