# Android AutoCompleteTextView with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, autocompletetextview

I am using `FirebaseListAdapter` to populate my `AutoCompleteTextView`. I want to return database based on the `GeoPoints` stored on firebase. The keys are displayed in the Logcat but the app crashes.

Logcat Crashed:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at com.android.avad.adapters.FirebaseListAdapter.addSingle(FirebaseListAdapter.java:197)
                                                                    at com.android.avad.fragments.SearchFragment$5$1.onDataChange(SearchFragment.java:480)
```

Logcat which shows the values:

```
10-24 14:17:55.574 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/FirebaseApp: Notifying background state change listeners.
10-24 14:17:55.877 9952-9952/com.android.avad I/SearchFragment: Contact permissions have already been granted. Displaying contact details.
10-24 14:17:55.950 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: Key Sameer entered the search area at [15.5425561,73.8210879]
10-24 14:17:55.951 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item added Sameer
10-24 14:17:55.962 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item updated: Sameer
10-24 14:17:55.985 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: Key Sameer entered the search area at [15.5425561,73.8210879]
10-24 14:17:55.986 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item added Sameer
10-24 14:17:55.987 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item updated: Sameer
10-24 14:17:56.492 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: Key Sameer entered the search area at [15.5425561,73.8210879]
10-24 14:17:56.494 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item added Sameer
10-24 14:17:56.495 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item updated: Sameer
10-24 14:17:58.742 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/FirebaseListAdapter: filter for S, results nr: 16
10-24 14:17:58.962 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/FirebaseListAdapter: filter for Sa, results nr: 16
10-24 14:18:02.063 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: Key Sameer entered the search area at [15.5425561,73.8210879]
10-24 14:18:02.079 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/SearchFragment: item added Sameer
10-24 14:18:02.104 9952-9952/com.android.avad D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

This is the code I am using for queries -

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Interests");

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("GeoPoints");
        geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
        mItemListAdapter = new ItemListAdapter(mDatabase.equalTo("GeoPoints"),  R.layout.auto_complete_items, getActivity());

 private void startGeoQuery(){
        query = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, 1);
        query.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Key " + key + " entered the search area at [" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude + "]");
                DatabaseReference tempRef = mDatabase.child(key);
                tempRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        // I  add the deal only if it doesn't exist already in the adapter
                        String key = snapshot.getKey();
                        if (!mItemListAdapter.exists(key)) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "item added " + key);
                            mItemListAdapter.addSingle(snapshot);
                            mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            //...otherwise I will update the record
                            Log.d(TAG, "item updated: " + key);
                            mItemListAdapter.update(snapshot, key);
                            mItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "cancelled with error:" + databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
```

This is my `ItemListAdapter` with extends `FirebaseListAdapter` -

```
 public ItemListAdapter(Query ref , int layout, Activity activity) {
    super(ref,Search.class,layout,activity);
    }

    /**
     * Bind an instance of the ExampleObject class to our view. This method is called by <code>FirebaseListAdapter</code>
     * when there is a data change, and we are given an instance of a View that corresponds to the layout that we passed
     * to the constructor, as well as a single ExampleObject instance that represents the current data to bind.
     *
     * @param v    A view instance corresponding to the layout we passed to the constructor.
     * @param model An instance representing the current state of a message
     */

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Search model) {
        TextView body = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.auto_text);
        // populate the list element
        body.setText(model.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Search> filters(List<Search> models, CharSequence constraint) {
        List<Search> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < models.size(); i++) {
            /* implement your own filtering logic
             * and then call  filterList.add(models.get(i));
             */
            filterList.add(models.get(i));
        }
        return filterList;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Search> filterKeys(List<Search> mModels) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719402/how-can-i-load-an-autocompletetextview-from-a-list-of-firebase-data

Answer (score 0):

```
reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter <String> adp;
uname=(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.uname);
adp = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,list);
uname.setThreshold(1);
uname.setAdapter(adp);
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                if(dsp!= null){
                    for (DataSnapshot dsp1 : dsp.getChildren()){
                        list.add(String.valueOf(dsp1.getKey()));
                        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

            }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```