# Firebase - Json with firebase keys

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble with a data import to the firebase, I've transformed an excel spreadsheet into csv and then the conversation to a JSON file, the Firebase register is not normally manufactured, however I'd like to know how to generate keys with the data instead of having a numerical order. If anyone knows of a grateful solution right away.

### Import JSON

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Keys format

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I think the provided information is quite less to understand. And If you can post your code, It would be very helpful for people who wants to help you.

Comment: @MaulikDodia when uploading the json to the console, he wants to generate the same keys we get when we use a `push()` instead of the numeric ones (0,1,2,...)

Comment: If the Json is starting of Array then he has to make changes in Json structure as Firebase doesn't work with Array structure. If you import as an Array structure, Internally It makes it as object. I had faced this Issue and asked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752496/reading-data-from-firebase-importing-json-file-to-firebase-console-which-is-a-a). You can checkout that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Firebase Realtime Database in which you can upload a JSON file using the Firebase Console and generate those random keys in the same time. You need to do it programmatically.

So to solve this problem, first you need to parse that file and use `push()` method to generate a unique random key for each product.