# How to use AutocompleteTextview with Firebase recycler adapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I've been searching about autocomplete textview but I can't seem figure out how can i implement it in firebase recycler adapter ? I saw this thread:  [How can I load an AutoCompleteTextView from a list of Firebase data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719402/how-can-i-load-an-autocompletetextview-from-a-list-of-firebase-data)

But I don't know how I can implement it in my program .

Here's my portion of my code ,

```
private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
    String spinnerSearchs=spinnerSearch.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(spinnerSearchs.equals("Book Title")){
        Query firebaseQuerySearch = mBookDatabase.orderByChild("bookTitle").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions bookOptions= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Book>().setQuery(firebaseQuerySearch,Book.class).build();
        mBook = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Book, UsersViewHolder>(bookOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final UsersViewHolder holder, final int position,final Book model) {
                holder.setDetails(model.getBookId(),model.getBookTitle(),model.getAuthorName());
                holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Borrow.class);
                        intent.putExtra(BOOK_ID,model.getBookId());
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            }

            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_layout,parent,false);

                return new UsersViewHolder(view,bookList);
            }
        };
        mSearchList.setAdapter(mBook);
        }  else if(spinnerSearchs.equals("Author")){
        Query firebaseQuerySearch = mBookDatabase.orderByChild("authorName").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions bookOptions= new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Book>().setQuery(firebaseQuerySearch,Book.class).build();
        mBook = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Book, UsersViewHolder>(bookOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(final UsersViewHolder holder, final int position,final Book model) {
                holder.setDetails(model.getBookId(),model.getBookTitle(),model.getAuthorName());
                holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Borrow.class);
                        intent.putExtra(BOOK_ID,model.getBookId());
                        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
            }

            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_layout,parent,false);

                return new UsersViewHolder(view,bookList);
            }
        };
        mSearchList.setAdapter(mBook);
    }
    mBook.startListening();


}
```