# How to add firebase data to Spinner android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase. I want to add Firebase data to my spinner. I followed this answer [How to get a String List from Firebase to fill a Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492827/how-to-get-a-string-list-from-firebase-to-fill-a-spinner) but my spinner doesn't receive anything.

[image: Este é o meu node no firebase]

This is my code:

```
//Value event listener for realtime data update
        ref.child("Tabela-Consulta").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                final List<String> nomeConsulta = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //Getting the data from snapshot
                    TabelaConsulta consultaName = postSnapshot.child("nomeconsulta").getValue(TabelaConsulta.class);
                    nomeConsulta.add(consultaName.getConsultanome());


                    // Creating adapter for spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nomeConsulta);
                    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    // attaching data adapter to spinner
                    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

My data model:

```
public class TabelaConsulta {

    private String consultanome;



    public TabelaConsulta(){

    }


    public String getConsultanome() {
        return  consultanome;
    }

    public void setConsultanome(String consultanome){
        this.consultanome = consultanome;
    }



}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your data model. What does `consultaName.getConsultanome()` supposed to return. Spinner code looks ok.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Your current model can only have one consultant name. Why do you even want a spinner ? If you want to store an array of consultants, then you need to correct your data model. Also Don't create an adapter on every callback. Modify the data in the adapter in the adapter instead

Comment: ok. Modify how? can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myRef.child("Tabela-Consulta").child("nomeconsulta").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> nomeConsulta = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String consultaName = areaSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                nomeConsulta.add(consultaName);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nomeConsulta);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(skularAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Remember to define your firebase reference:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("YOUR_REFERENCE");
```

And define your spinner:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(YOUR_SPINNER);
```

Also make make your database look like this:

[image: Something]

By adding your values like this:

[image: Something_more]

Put your values in `" "` and then close everything with `[]` .

Hope it helps!

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below

Firebase Url :`https://example-id:firebaseio.com/Tabela-Consulta`

`MainActivity.java` :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private List<String> nomeConsulta = new ArrayList<String>();
        private ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
        private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
        private Spinner mSpinner

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nomeConsulta);
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            mSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.your_reference_spinner);
            mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            mDatabaseReference.child("Tabela-Consulta").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TabelaConsulta data = snapshot.getValue(TabelaConsulta.class);
                    nomeConsulta.add(data.getConsultanome());
                }
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: How is the data actually connected to the spinner adapter in your code ?

Comment: This is one of my doubts.

Comment: `Spinner` is view of referenced from your `xml`, I can't put all code with the answer. And please don't copy and paste. Try to get an idea first from any answer