# How to add firebase specific data to Spinner in android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase. I want to add Firebase specific data to my spinner. I view this content [This help content, but I don't get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41849638/how-to-add-firebase-data-to-spinner-android)[image]

i would like to fetch the username into my spinner.

My code

```
private void showdata()
{
    spinnerRef.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot item:snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                spinnerList.add((item.child("username").getValue()).toString());
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, you have any errors?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I don't have errors encountering so far

Comment: So, the data cannot retrieve?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine Yes :<

Comment: First step is to stop ignoring errors. At its minimum, `onCancelled` should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: As also Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment, first of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Please also respond with @.

Comment: @Koykoy200078 have you solved the problem?