# How to get Firebase Realtime Data Spinner Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to pull data from the spinner with Firebase. I uploaded my data to Firebase. I want to show this data in Spinner in Android Studio. I couldn't figure out how to do this. Can you help me?

Link to the Firebase image: https://www.hizliresim.com/5cg8gxy There will be 60 pieces of data here.

Comment: No need to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To the values for those 4 fields, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
db.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            String one = snapshot.child("One").getValue(String.class);
            String two = snapshot.child("Two").getValue(String.class);
            String three = snapshot.child("Three").getValue(String.class);
            String four = snapshot.child("Four").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", one + "/" + two + "/" + three + "/" + four);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

One thing to note is that those 4 fields are added right below the root reference of your database. While the data can be read, as you can see above, it's best to add those fields under a [pushed IDs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()). In this way, you can add more objects inside your database.

Comment: So how do I do this on the spinner?

Comment: You'll need an adapter. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171376/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-and-show-it-in-a-spinner/53171680#53171680). Is for the Realtime Database, but you can easily adapt it.

Comment: Hey there. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?