# Why data from firebase database did not show in Spinner?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As refer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492827/how-to-get-a-string-list-from-firebase-to-fill-a-spinner). I want to try in my coding apps. But it didnt retrieve any data from my firebase database. I just cant figure out how to fix it. Can someone please help me. Is there any idea, where did I miss?

My firebase database as show image below:-

[image]

Spinner coding:-

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

mDatabase.child("Advertisement").child(mAuth.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                //final List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> identity = new ArrayList<>();
                identity.add(0, "Choose Tuition Centre");

                for (DataSnapshot nameSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String tuitionName = nameSnapshot.child("adstuitioname").getValue(String.class);
                    identity.add(tuitionName);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> nameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RatingActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, identity);
                nameAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mName.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Item Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position) +" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Comment: If the app closes, then there is a logcat that you've not uploaded to this post. You are also ignoring all errors in `onCancelled`, so please put something there

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @UmangBurman my apps crash so cant figure out whether the spinner show the data or not

Comment: Can you show the logcat somehow in the question so that we can understand

Comment: @UmangBurman Sir.. I already fix it other ways and I cant retrieve the data from the firebase database. I already edit my question.

Comment: Are you getting any data in Identify List?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181057/discussion-between-daisy-and-umang-burman).

Comment: Do you any message in `databaseError`? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo Dont have sir...

Comment: @cricket_007 Sir.. I already fix it other ways and I cant retrieve the data from the firebase database. I already edit my question.

Comment: If you've fixed it, then feel free to add your own answer

Comment: No @cricket_007, I try to fix it other ways, but still cant retrieve the data from the firebase database to spinner.

Comment: You're getting an error somewhere. Please try to add log statements to your code for the spots where you think data should be added to the arraylist, and then edit your question to include those logs. That will help us to help you better

Comment: @cricket_007 my apps didnot crash sir, the problem is I cant retrieve the data from database into my spinner.

Comment: I did not say your *app crashes*. **You did** say your "app suddenly closes". I'm not sure why you're trying to argue with me when I'm trying to help you help yourself by *debugging your own code*... Basically, if you just look at your Firebase loop and compare what is actually in the database, you have an extra object above where you seem to think `adstuitioname` is available, therefore, accessing that will make "your app crash suddenly". **Or**  `databaseError` in your code is actually being set, you're ***ignoring it***. The answers below look correct, but I can't test them

Comment: @cricket_007 omg, honestly I didnt arguer with you sir, I already edited my question, the problem now is I cant retrieve the data from firebase into my spinner :'D

Comment: and yes, I'm also referring the below answer from Maam Ami :D

Answer (score 1):

Add listener as below :

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef =  
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
mDatabaseRef.child("Advertisement")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for (DataSnapshot snapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) 
                     {
                        Advertisementject advertisement= 
                                snapshot.getValue(Advertisement.class);
                        //replace Object.class with your class name
                        //get your key value here from your "Custom class" 
                        // which contains "adstutioname" 
                        // add in list
                        list.add(advertisement.getAdstutuioname());
                    }

                    //set adapter
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

generate class like this

```
public class Advertisement{

@SerializedName("adstutuioname")
@Expose
private String adstutuioname;

public String getAdstutuioname() {
  return adstutuioname;
}

public void setAdstutuioname(String adstutuioname) {
  this.adstutuioname = adstutuioname;
}

}
```

- Your class contains all your params and .
- Replace Object with this class

Comment: Can you please give an example for this ? 1) get your key value here from your "Custom class" which contains "adstutioname". 2) add in list

Comment: I already create my advertisement java class which consists of constructor and getter.

Comment: but this one --- >//get your key value here from your "Custom class"  which contains "adstutioname" andd this one ---> // add in list. How ? :D

Comment: So now you will get Advertisement advertisement instance. then access Advertisement.getAdstutuioname() and add it to your list

Comment: String tuitionName = dataSnapshot.child("adstuitioname").getValue().toString();

Comment: Is it like this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181077/discussion-between-daisy-and-ami-trambadia).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the problem is with your getValue() method. Firebase getValue method returns an Object, and you are expecting a String. Please modify this line to convert your Object to String -

```
String tuitionName = nameSnapshot.child("adstuitioname").getValue(String.class).toString();
```

Comment: Why areaName? Im using this one sir, String tuitionName = nameSnapshot.child("adstuitioname").getValue(String.class);

Comment: Sir... still the same. But I fix it other ways and I cant retrieve the data from the firebase database. I already edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're trying to read once, or watch changes [Difference between addValueEventListener() and addListenerForSingleValueEvent() of firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41579000/difference-between-addvalueeventlistener-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent)

First things first, look if you are getting a database error

```
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Toast or print the databaseError, don't ignore it
}
```

Then look where you're adding a listener - `mDatabase.child("Advertisement").child(mAuth.getUid()).`, which from your picture is every element at the level of `-LNZ6...`.

For that level, you have a list of object's, so you can need to use a loop, and as shown from some examples on Firebase site, it's recommended that you make an object, but you still can use `child` method for a certain field as you're trying to do

But if a field doesn't exist, you get null value, and Adapters cannot hold nulls, so you must ignore or set some default value.

```
ArrayList<String> identity = new ArrayList<>();
identity.add(0, "Choose Tuition Centre");

for (DataSnapshot nameSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())  {
    String tuitionName = nameSnapshot.child("adstuitioname").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d("DEBUG TUITION", String.valueOf(tuitionName);  // look for this in your logs 
    identity.add(tuitionName == null ? "none" : tuitionName);
}
ArrayAdapter<String> nameAdapter =...
```

Comment: Sir, I try already, still the same, this = {RatingActivity$2@6534} 
dataSnapshot = {DataSnapshot@6536} "DataSnapshot { key = 52ictJZU8TWWqOsGbpnQ6GDCYUv1, value = null }"
identity = {ArrayList@6537}  size = 1

Comment: I want to fill the spinner with the data from the Firebase Database. If the tuition centre change it name, so the list data in the Spinner also change.

Comment: Then it seems `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is empty and you're not adding the listener to the correct object. For example, how do you know that `mAuth.getUid()` needs to be added? Is that the right ID?

Comment: Plus, your comment there says `52ictJZU8TWWqOsGbpnQ6GDCYUv1`, but that's not in the pictures shown