# Spinner Does Not Retrieve Any Data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a spinner validation where if the user did not select any tuition centre name, it will toast a message. Then I want to fill the spinner with the data from firebase database. As refer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492827/how-to-get-a-string-list-from-firebase-to-fill-a-spinner). I want to try this in my coding apps. But it didn't retrieve any data from my firebase database. Its been few days, I still can't figure out, can someone please help me....

My firebase database as show image below:-

[image]

Spinner coding:-

```
   DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mDatabaseRef.child("Advertisement").child(mAuth.getUid())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    //ArrayList<String> identity = new ArrayList<>();
                    final List<String> identity = new ArrayList<String>();
                    identity.add(0, "Choose Tuition Centre");

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Advertisement advertisement = snapshot.getValue(Advertisement.class);
                        identity.add(advertisement.getAdstuitioname());
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> nameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RatingActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, identity);
                    nameAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    mName.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
                {

                }
            });

    mName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            if(position==0)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Item Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position) +" Selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

My apps output interface:-

[image]

Comment: did you debug? is there any data within snapshot?

Comment: @ZaidMirza I already run the apps, but no data sir.

Comment: mAuth.getUid() returns correct UID ?

Comment: @ZaidMirza Yes sir, If I did not put that coding, my apps crash. Can I have your email sir? So that I can email you my coding, easier for out discussion..

Comment: Are you getting data in DataSnapshot ?

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh I want to get the data from firebase. Im not sure to use what method. Im just referring to the tutorial...

Comment: Please learn how to debug

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh yes there are childs...

Comment: Okay just do one thing can you send the code.

Comment: @PradeepDeshmukh your email sir

Comment: pradeepemc3@gmail.com

Comment: you have to put the detail in the database instead at xml?

Comment: @Zuhrain In my database there's data

Comment: @Zuhrain ada da data dalam firebase tu

Comment: ok dah jumpa something, dekat sini `mDatabaseRef.child("Advertisement").child(mAuth.getUid())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()` sepatutnya ada satu lagi child.

Comment: @Zuhrain Tak dapat, tu da ada 2 child da. Perlu tambah which child?

Comment: email. ticherhaz@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are nested ids the actual data is after 2 ids. you need to traverse. Just replace the for loop's code to this code.

```
 for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
      identity.add(dataSnapshot1.child("adstuitioname").getValue(String.class));
         }
     }
```

keep rest of as it is.

Comment: Still cannot retrieve the data into my Spinner sir :'(